# Error "PolicySet json is not valid" when Bootstrap on Postman Sitecore XC 10 .1 SDK

Tags: sitecore-commerce, deployment

I use `Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.SDK.7.0.55` with `Customer.Sample.Solution` solution. I entered the config and global information. Then proceed to deploy to the `CommerceAuthoring_Sc` directory of `Sitecore XC`. Everything seems to be working fine when I use Postman until when I POST `{{OpsApiHost}}/{{OpsApi}}/Bootstrap()` it returns `PolicySet json is not valid`. How to fix this error?

Update: I tried filling in `PlaceholderFor...` fields in the JSON files, I fixed this error but all the data in my `HabitatAuthoring` environment is lost (I have installed `Storefront XC` sample) . There is nothing I can do but reinstall `Sitecore XC`.

How do I fix `PolicySet json is not valid` error without causing data loss for `HabitatAuthoring` environment?

Answer (score 0):

This is not becuase of JSON format.

You should check the namespace of your custom policy class.

For more detail you can follow the below URL:

http://jitendrasoni.blogspot.com/2020/10/sitecore-xc-93-investigation-and-fix.html